# Grails: Incompatible Strings for Range: starting String is longer than ending string

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have the following action in one of my controllers:

```
def logUpdate() {
    def report = Report.findById(params.id)
    def update = report.reportLog[params.logIndex..-1]
    render(template: "/report/LogTemplate", model: [update: update])
}
```

And when this action is called the app throws an exception with the message "Incompatible Strings for Range: starting String is longer than ending string"

Comment: What is the value of `params.logIndex`? Since it will be string you have to cast it to a number. Try using `report.reportLog[params.logIndex.toInteger()..-1]` provided it actually is a number value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert the *logIndex* parameter to an integer:

```
def logIndex = params.int('logIndex')
def update = report.reportLog[logIndex..-1]
```